# silent mode installation of setup files in Windows server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I want to install some softwares such as notepad++, safari etc in silent mode using command prompt. And my OS is win2k8r2.
I placed two executables npp.6.3.3.Installer.exe and SafariStup 4.2.exe in a folder in c drive and used command line arguments as below..
c:\AllFiles>npp.6.3.3.Installer.exe -s
it executes, but shows dialog boxes that was not expected.Please help...

Answer (score 0):

Each program is going to be different, some don't even support silent installations. From command line if you do `yourfile.exe /?` it should tell you available options.

Comment: ya you are right. I need to find the software which support command line, and install using that.                                                   Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For Notepad++, I recommend simply downloading the ZIP package (not the EXE installer), unpacking it to the desired location, and adding a Start Menu shortcut.

You don't need to *install* it per se.